# Rectilinear Steiner Tree Heuristic (Python)

Tags: python, image, charts, connected-components

I have an image consisting of black and white pixels. I'd like to mostly reserve the shape of the original image, but for my purposes I need the black pixels to be orthogonally connected.

I have tried [searching the problem up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_Steiner_tree), and learned that the problem is NP-hard. Therefore, I'm expecting a heuristic that will run in reasonable time for a ~2000x2000 image.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)